# What is difference between Liberty Core,Liberty Base,Liberty Network Deployment versions?

Tags: websphere-liberty

Is there any document which provide information about difference between Liberty Core, Liberty Base, Liberty Network Deployment versions?

I want to use Liberty and deploy my application in Docker Data Center. But I am not sure which version of Liberty should I use. Also what is the main difference between these versions? My applications will have different technology stacks like REST, SOAP, EJB, RPC, Caching, JPA etc.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any document which provide information about difference between Liberty Core,Liberty Base,Liberty Network Deployment versions.

These are called "editions" and each edition includes a set of features.  The smallest edition is "core" and it contains the most minimal set of features.  Each successive edition adds a few more features, with ND basically including everything (except the zOS specific features).

Here is a chart to help you visualize how the editions relate to one another.

[image: Liberty edition comparisons]

Note that this image is already out of date, because more features have been delivered since it was created.

To see the official table of what features are included in each edition, see [Liberty Features](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html).